# Connection services in different containers in the same ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I am currently running two services in two separate containers in a single ec2 instance: a web application and an api respectively. what do i use to connect the web application to the api in the same ec2 instance? I have used the private IP and private dns in the web config to point to the api but i am still getting timeout error.

Comment: i am not sure i follow what you mean. Both containers have been generated by use of a task definition. api has the following port mapping: 7001:8080 and web application has the following port mapping: 7002:80

Comment: What type of web application? If this is a client-side rendered application like React or Vue, then the code would actually be running on the end user's computer, not on ECS, so the private IP wouldn't work.

Answer (score -1):

You may use docker-compose by default the containers will be in same network and they will be able to communicate with each other.

Comment: i am not sure i follow what you mean. Both containers have been generated by use of a task definition. api has the following port mapping: 7001:8080 and web application has the following port mapping: 7002:80

Comment: Kindly add the docker code for more explanation

Comment: there is no docker code. this is done through the use of task definitions and created using aws console.

Comment: You didn't mention in your question that containers are being created using task definitions. I would recommend to update the question with precise information. Now the issue would still be same that the container would not be in the same network hence they aren't able to communicate with each other

Comment: @deepbajaj The question was tagged with ECS.

Comment: @MarkB Just tagging doesn't change the context of the question